# detect content from zip file without uncompress it

Tags: linux, shell, zip

I'm trying to check a lot of zip files to make sure it contains the right directories. what I've done is  looping all the zip files then use `unzip` to uncompress and check it one by one.But the CPU and time consuming problem come up.And I believe the situation would be better if it's done without uncompressing stuff.So is there any other more effective solution for this work?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @deathApril,I'm working on linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do an actual unzip (uncompress) just list the contents on the zip file.
Not sure which unzip binary you are using but the [man page for unzip](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/unzip.html) have the list option:

`unzip -l`

From the [zip file format specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) it looks like it can then just skip to the next entry without doing any uncompressing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zipinfo](http://www.info-zip.org/mans/zipinfo.html) to list a zip file contents without extracting/uncompressing its data.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where such tricks don't work, unzip to `/dev/null` and redirect the standard output to file. This won't save you the CPU work, but it will save you the disk I/O associated with actually writing out all the files. The redirected standard output will still list the unzipped filenames.

Comment: How do you unzip to /dev/null (outside -l which doesn't unzip at all) ? According to its documentation, unzip either extracts files in the current directory, the directory specified by the -d option, or to stdout with the -c option. None of these allow redirecting the files to a device and the filenames to stdout.